# iOS UIAlertview with uitextview editable

Tags: ios, uitextview, uialertview

I'm searching for a way of putting an UITextView editable inside an UIAlertView.

I know how to put a simple textfield with :

```
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
```

But this isn't what i want. I want a bigger text input so a user can write a comment after a news for example.

Is this possible ?

Comment: so for this purpose why use a alert view? you can use a uiview with UITextView just add this as a subview when commenting.

Comment: i already have a comment list in a table view and i want to take out the "add a comment" from my view to take less place

Comment: so instead of showing an alertview you can add a uiview e.g.:[self.tableview addsubview:uiview]

Comment: or this custom control might help you https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Comment: It isn't possible to add views to a `UIAlertView` so getting what you are after with a `UITextView` and a `UIAlertView` isn't actually possible. However you can look for a custom alertView. Check out this Google search https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Custom+UI+Alertview&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=7lTbVMGAOs2q8wfo-ICICw#safe=active&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=Custom+UIAlertview&spell=1

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you are after isn't possible with a `UIAlertView`.

Apple don't allow developers to modify the view hierarchy of a `UIAlertView` or subclass it. Check out the [Apple Documentation for `UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html). Under the section marked **Subclassing note** you will find

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Unfortunately though because `UIAlertView` still has the `addSubview:` method so it contradicts what Apple are actually telling us but the reason this is still here is because `UIAlertView` is a subclass of `UIView` which has this method. So what Apple have done is they have overridden this method so that it does absolutely nothing so when you call `[myAlertView addSubview:myView];` will do nothing and no view will be added to the `UIAlertView`.

So to get the behavior you are after you will need to implement a Custom AlertView (Check out Google search for [Custom UIAlertView](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Custom%20UIAlertViews&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=91jbVJ7EAcmq8wen9oG4Cg#safe=active&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=Custom%20UIAlertView&spell=1)).

Fortunately in iOS 8 Apple introduced a new class called `UIAlertController` that allows you to get the behavior that you are after and they have deprecated the `UIAlertView` class.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom view into the alert view.

Change preferredStyle to .alert and .actionsheet as per the requirement.

```
func showPopUpWithTextView() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let margin:CGFloat = 8.0
        let rect = CGRect(x: margin, y: margin, width: alertController.view.bounds.size.width - margin * 4.0, height: 100.0)
        let textView = UITextView(frame: rect)
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear

        alertController.view.addSubview(textView)

        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Something", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("Submit")
            print(textView.text)
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("cancel")})

        alertController.addAction(submitAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})
    }
```

[image]

[image]